# ValidateCacheOutput function is never called while programmatically invalidating cached page

Tags: caching

I have a problem with programmatically invalidating cached page.

I coded a page for publishing RSS-feed, and the page is cached in a preset time interval, say in 3 minutes. However, when ever a new UMM message is raised and saved to the database, the page shall be re-cached.

For this task, I used a solution illustrated in MS document about "Programmatically Invalidating Cached Pages". Although I coded following function:

```
public static void ValidateCacheOutput(HttpContext context, Object data, ref HttpValidationStatus status)
        {
            if (((bool)context.Application["IsNewUMMRaised"]) == true)
                status = HttpValidationStatus.Invalid;
            else
                status = HttpValidationStatus.Valid;
        }
```

and added following code to the start of Page_load function.

```
Response.Cache.AddValidationCallback(new HttpCacheValidateHandler(ValidateCacheOutput), null);

Following code is executed when a UMM is saved to database.

 Application["IsNewUMMRaised"] = true;
```

The problem is that the above event handler function is never called when the web page is accessed, i.e. the page is re-cached in a preset time interval, even when application variable `IsNewUMMRaised` is set to true. I wonder why why it works this way, and how my code shall be modified so that the above event handler function is called when the page is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the problem seems being caused by Response.End() function which is called in the Page_load function. After this code line is removed, the event handler function is called properly when the page is accessed.

Comment: This is still a problem: after comment out Response.End() code line, RSS feeds works with FireFox, but it does not work with Internet Explorer, because output contains both RSS XML stuff and page HTML stuff. Internet Explorer does not tolerate page HTML stuff.

Comment: So the problem is not resolved yet. I wonder someone knows how to solve this problem. Thanks for your kind help.